# Where can you find the default property values for xaml layouts in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, layout, properties

I've read that to increase performance you shouldn't set the value of a property within a layout if it's the same as the default value for a layout. As a simple example, if I had a `StackLayout` and I wanted it to be oriented vertically, I might write

```
<StackLayout
    Orientation="Vertical"
    >
</StackLayout>
```

but I know from experience that `Vertical` is the default orientation for a StackLayout and thus setting this value is redundant and will reduce performance.

What I don't know is the default value for many other properties such as `Padding`, `Margin`, `HorizontalOptions`, `VerticalOptions` and everything else, and for other layouts such as `Grid`.

Is there a simpler way to find these values that avoids trialing each layout with and without setting the values?

Comment: Where did you read that? In my experience, the only place where it could have any noticeable impact is in a `style` declaration. And its very rarely an issue, even there. If you have performance problems, this won't be what is needed to fix them. Performance problems are dominated by "measure and layout" time. The usual fix is to find a way to make the performance with less nesting of layout classes (classes that can contain other elements as children, such as grid or stacklayout). Anyway, most options default to the most commonly used value. Zero for padding margin...

Comment: ... you'd have to find each property's doc page. E.g. StackLayout.Spacing says it defaults to `6`. If you find a doc page that doesn't say what the default is, and its not obvious what would be the most likely, then use comment feedback on that page to mention this missing info.

Comment: "By default, a StackLayout is oriented **vertically**".  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stacklayout

Answer (score 1):

You will find it mentioned in the Xamarin documentation or it API documentation, for instance:

- [HorizontalOptions/VerticalOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options) : default value is `LayoutOptions.Fill`.
- [Padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.layout.padding?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_Layout_Padding) : default is a `Thickness` type of 0 values.

If not mentioned in the documentation, you can look at the source code;:

- `HorizontalOptions, VerticalOptions, Margin` are `View`'s properties you will find their declaration in [View.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/b331f96bef28830961b249a5c4b556cc5cade0ec/Xamarin.Forms.Core/View.cs#L14-L26).
- For `StackLayout.Spacing` you will find it in [StackLayout.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/b331f96bef28830961b249a5c4b556cc5cade0ec/Xamarin.Forms.Core/StackLayout.cs#L12-L13) and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You could also double click the `StackLayout` in the Xaml to choose it. And then press F12 on keyboard. It would open a metadata for StackLayout.

In the comment of `Orientation`, the part of value would show the default.

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the value which indicates the direction which child elements are
    //     positioned.
    //
    // Value:
    //     A Xamarin.Forms.StackOrientation which indicates the direction children layouts
    //     flow. The default value is Vertical.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     Setting the Orientation of a StackLayout triggers a layout cycle if the stack
    //     is already inside of a parent layout. To prevent wasted layout cycles, set the
    //     orientation prior to adding the StackLayout to a parent.
```